# Link goods to sector (UCC to NAICS)

Tags: data-request

Universal Classification Code (UCCs) are six digit codes that identify items or groups of items. Here are some UCCs:

- 190903 Food and non-alcoholic beverages at restaurants, cafes, fast food places on trips
- 190904 Food and beverages purchased and prepared by CU on trips
- 200900 Alcoholic beverages at restaurants, cafes, bars on trips 210110 Rent of dwelling
- 210210 Lodging away from home on trips
- 210310 Housing for someone at school
- 210901 Ground rent - owned home

They are for example being used in the consumption expenditure survey to identify consumption items.

Is there any way (e.g. existing bridge data base) to link these UCC to the sector of production? For example, NAICS?

Comment: Are you talking about $GS_1$ ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1_US

Comment: @VicAche There was a typo in the question, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any publicly-available concordance, and I can promise you that there's no clean mapping between UCC and NAICS. Obviously, some categories will map well at low granularity (UCC 190903 will definitely map to 722, for example).

While I'm sure it's fine for whatever you're doing if multiple UCC codes map to a single NAICS code, the big problem is that some UCC codes will map to multiple NAICS codes. For example, 190113, "lunch at vending machines and mobile vendors" will map to some combination of NAICS 454210, "vending machine operators" and NAICS 722330, "mobile food services".

The way this is usually handled is through some form of allocation— you assume, for example, that the CES population you're observing has exactly the same distribution of expenditures as the overall economy.